# Restore deleted script blocks

Tags: google-apps-script

please help, I accidentally removed a huge portion of my codes in Google Script and accidentally saved it. Is there any way I can "Undo" and I get my previous version back?

Comment: Try  contacting google support if it's not in your version history.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for your comment, I did contact Google Support, but they say that App Script is not supported. 

"Please keep in mind that Apps Script is not supported by our Google Workspace Team and we do not have tools, training or access to view any information in relation to Apps Script accounts or issues. Nonetheless, I’ll be happy to go the extra mile for you and help you by sharing Help Center articles or Forums that are publicly available to help you narrow down your issue."

To which they directed me here. And I have to say that they are right. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. In the script editor, click **Use legacy editor**.
2. In the left-hand pane, click the name of the script file you want to restore.
3. Choose **File > See version history**.
4. Select the version you want to restore.
5. Click **Restore**.

Alternatively, use the revision history list to copy the code of the version you want to keep and paste it elsewhere.

To return to the new Monaco editor, click **Use new editor**.

Comment: Another one of those `you can only doit the the legacy editor`.